# How to get data from MySQL table based on a junction table

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to tackle this problem but couldn't do it properly, any help is really appreciated.

**This is the Distance calculation query based on latitude, longitude and distance in KMs**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT *,
                (
                        ((acos(sin((27.6677608 * pi() / 180)) * sin((activities.latitude * pi() / 180)) +
                               cos((27.6677608 * pi() / 180)) * cos((activities.latitude * pi() / 180)) *
                               cos(((68.8543843 - activities.longitude) * pi() / 180)))) * 180 / pi()) * 60 *
                        1.1515 * 1.609344
                    )
                    as distance
         FROM `activities`
         WHERE is_public = true
           AND (
                     DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) > 0
                 OR
                     TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(end_time), TIME(start_time))) > 10
             )
     ) markers
WHERE distance <= 22
```

**This is the activity related table ER diagram**
[image]

Now what i have been trying to do is that the user provides `latitude`, `longitude` and `distance` from which i calculate `activities` within the `distance`, `lat/longs` provided by the user.

**PROBLEM** => problem is that i want to get `activities` which are not only close to user's `lat/long` and `distance` but also matching certain `interest_id` from `activity_interests` table.

**SCENARIO** => for instance, i provide these details as payload

```json
{
    "latitude": "27.6677608",
    "longitude": "68.8543843",
    "distance": 7,
    "interests": [1,2,3]
}
```

Now i want `Activities` which have all above payload `Interest ids` present in the `Activity_interests` table and still do the distance calculation for which i have provided the above SQL query.

**MySQL version 8.0 is used**

Thank you, and i hope i explained it well.

Comment: Plan A:  Filter on distance, _then_ filter on the other criteria.  Plan B: do the opposite.  Question:  Which order is more likely to be faster (based on your understanding of the data)?  Once you answer that, we can help you design the query (and manybe the schema) to optimize that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
   ,st_distance_sphere(POINT(68.8543843, 27.6677608 ), POINT(a.`longitude`, a.`latitude` ))/1000   as distance
FROM `activities` a INNER JOIN `activity_interests` ai ON a.id = ai.activity_id 
WHERE is_public = true
   AND (
             DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) > 0
         OR
             TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(end_time), TIME(start_time))) > 10
     ) 
     AND ai.interest_id IN (1,2,3)
HAVING distance <= 22
```

As long as you don't provide data, I can only hint at how it would look like.

```
SELECT a.*,st_distance_sphere(POINT(68.8543843, 27.6677608 ), POINT(`longitude`, `latitude` ))/1000   as distance
FROM `activities` a INNER JOIN `activity_interests` ai ON a.id = ai.activity_id 
WHERE is_public = true
   AND (
             DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) > 0
         OR
             TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(end_time), TIME(start_time))) > 10
     ) 
     AND SUM(ai.interest_id =1) + SUM(ai.interest_id =2) + SUM(ai.interest_id =3) = 3
GROUP BY a.id,distance
HAVING distance <= 22
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but the problem with this is that it brings back all the tables containing even one of the ids present in interests array, for example if `pool party` activity has only one interest with id of 1 in `Activity_interests` table, that is also included in the result whereas what i want is strictly those `Activities` which has all the interests provided in the `interests` array.

Comment: Provide please a [mre](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) data and tables as a ddl or a dbfiddle